# Separate strings with regex and Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, pandas, dataframe

I have below content and I need to separate third part as below with Pandas in Python:

My string:

```
FA0003 -BL- FA0005-BL
FA0004-BL-FA0008-BL
```

My Expected:

```
FA0005
FA0008
```

Imagine I have a string like this in a column named A, the regex of below string for retrieving FA0003 is as below, but I don't know how to retrieve FA0005?

```
FA0003 -BL- FA0005-BL
df[A].str.extract(r'(\w+\s*)', expand=False)
FA0003
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```py
^(?:[^-]*-){2}\s*([^-]+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aKdAKw/1)

In Pandas, use it with your current code:

```py
df[A].str.extract(r'^(?:[^-]*-){2}\s*([^-]+)', expand=False)
```

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:[^-]*-){2}` - two occurrences of any chars other than `-` and then a `-`
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces (this is used to trim the output)
- `([^-]+)` - Capturing group 1 (the return value): one or more chars other than `-`.